# LangChain Chunking leaving 1 letter per Chunk... How to fix and have legitimate Chunk lengths?

Tags: chunks, langchain, large-language-model

I am getting chunks that are literally only one character long. Like this:

```
Chunk 1: C
Chunk 2: o
Chunk 3: l
Chunk 4: o
.
.
.
```

Not sure why, and my code is here... I separate it from PDF to long string because I want overlapping chunks, and I don't think that's possible with just page outputs.

Below is my code using LangChain RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter. I tried using different separators (even a % to reduce chunking if that was the issue) but the problem persists.

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

#Grab pdf text and put into one huge unstructured string
reader = PdfReader('/content/Colorado_property_law_first50pages.pdf')

colorado_raw = ''
for page_num in range(0,len(reader.pages)):
  page = reader.pages[page_num]
  colorado_raw += page.extract_text()

#Use a text splitter for chunking

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    separators = ["%"],
    chunk_size = 3000,
    chunk_overlap  = 50,
    length_function = len,
    add_start_index = True,
)
#Split the long unstructured string
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents(colorado_raw)
```

Here is sample output:

```
[Document(page_content='C', metadata={'start_index': 0}), Document(page_content='o', metadata={'start_index': 0}), Document(page_content='l', metadata={'start_index': 0}), Document(page_content='o', metadata={'start_index': 0}),......
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to the signature of `create_documents` at [TextSplitter](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain/text_splitter.html#TextSplitter)

```
def create_documents(
        self, texts: List[str], metadatas: Optional[List[dict]] = None
    ) -> List[Document]
```

so `create_documents` need a list of string. so you can change the code as follows(comments along with code):

```
#Grab pdf text and put into one huge unstructured string
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader('data_source/lobel-frog-toad.pdf') # my source for debug

#colorado_raw = ''
colorado_raw=[] # comment about and create a list
for page_num in range(0,len(reader.pages)):
    
    page = reader.pages[page_num]
    #colorado_raw += page.extract_text()
    colorado_raw.append(page.extract_text()) # append to list
```

and then call the split

```
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    separators = [","," "], # need to put separator based on text
    chunk_size =50,
    chunk_overlap  = 20,
    length_function = len,
    add_start_index = True

)
#Split the long unstructured string
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents(colorado_raw)
chunks[:5]
```

[image]

Note: You can explore nltk package to enhance the code or some suggestion [listed here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/3786)